# Does a free falling shell receive Hawking radiation?

Tags: general-relativity, hawking-radiation

According to the equivalence principle, a free radially-falling observer moving towards black hole does not see Hawking radiation. Does a free falling shell see Hawking radiation? If not, how does the radiation "goes through" the shell and reach the infinity?

Comment: why would the equivalence principle imply that?

Comment: See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/634972/how-does-hawking-radiation-emerge-from-the-shadows)