# Are black holes black body?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, temperature, thermal-radiation, hawking-radiation

I've read online that black holes are almost ideal black bodies. But for a body to be called an ideal black body it should emit all the rays of all the wavelengths but black holes don't, so how can we call them black bodies?

so, what happens to the energy which black holes absorb?

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634972/123208 but the main answer there is rather technical.

Comment: [Black hole greybody factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_greybody_factors)

Comment: Are you asking why and how black holes can emit radiation? Or do you already know about [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) and you're asking why don't see visible light emitted from the black hole?

Comment: The last part of your question is the easiest to answer: Whoever finds out what actually happens to the mass and energy that black holes absorb will get a Nobel Prize in physics for sure. We simply don't know, yet. Nobody has been able to measure it with current instruments, with one exception: when black holes merge, a sizable part of their mass-energy gets converted to gravitational waves. I am not an expert in the field, so I will let somebody else write a detailed answer about that process.

Comment: "*what happens to the energy which black holes absorb?*" - Black hols don't absorb any energy, as we observe from outside. All incoming energy and matter remain forever just outside the horizon and add up to the total mass of the black hole.